# JOLT Transformation and add a new array to the output

Tags: json, apache-nifi, transformation, jolt

I have the following JSON input that I would like to transform using JOLT:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "tests": [
      {
        "id": 304674,
        "name": "Test Number One",
        "description": "First Test"
      },
      {
        "id": 12345,
        "name": "Test Number Two",
        "description": "Second test"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like the output to rename some things and then add a new array called locations, resulting in the following desired output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "tests": [
      {
        "TestID": 304674,
        "Name": "Test Number One",
        "Description": "First Test",
        "locations": [
          "Paris",
          "London"
        ],
      },
      {
        "id": 12345,
        "name": "Test Number Two",
        "description": "Second test",
        "locations": [
          "Paris",
          "London"
        ],
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried the following JOLT spec on apache-nifi but when I run it I only get "Paris" for locations.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "tests": {
          "*": {
            "id": "data.tests[&1].TestID",
            "name": "data.tests[&1].Name",
            "description": "data.tests[&1].Description"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "tests": {
          "*": {
            "locations": ["Paris", "London"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far so good attempt. I can add the following points of view :

- no need to repeat the literals but use ampersand notations such as **&2**(*eg.:going two levels up the tree and grabbing the literal `tests`*), **&3**(`data`)
- **&(0,1)** to represent the **1**st occurence of the asterisk from the levelcurrent(**0**th)
- **"locations": ["Paris", "London"]** might be directly added within the shift transformation(without needing an extra transformation) while renaming the attributes for the current objects

So, you can use the following spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "tests": {
          "*": {
            "id": "&3.&2[&1].TestID",
            "n*": "&3.&2[&1].N&(0,1)",
            "d*": "&3.&2[&1].D&(0,1)",
            "#Paris|#London": "&3.&2[&1].locations"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you Barbaros.  That worked beautifully.  And thank you for the explanation behind the specifics in your answer.  It is very helpful.

Comment: Nice to help @MichaelWyatt , welcome to the community.